# Options in facets disappear when more than one value is selected

Tags: search

We have setup a custom search with [Search Api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and [Search API Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr). In a facet we want to allow the selection of multiple values, with the normal link widget. We have configured the facet to use the `OR` operator. Everything works as expected until we select more than one value. With more than one value selected, the search result is still correct, but all other options disappear. This is not the behaviour we want, we would like to continue displaying all options, in the same way it works after the user selected a single element.

[image: Everything works fine with one value selected]
[image: With two values selected all other values disappear]

Comment: Can you specify what your problem is? Are you still wanting all the facet options to stay open?

Comment: Yes, that's what we want. I've clarified the description.

Comment: I've found a bug report: https://www.drupal.org/node/1854762.

Comment: Gotcha, I'm voting to close because bug-related problems are best left answered in the issue queue instead of here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is related to a bug.

Comment: An other bug report:https://www.drupal.org/node/2474661

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with solr 3.5 and the `search_api_solr` module, the bug is described here:https://www.drupal.org/node/2474661 the bug report includes a patch that fixes the issue. With the patch in place everything works as expected.